# iOS JSON Error: NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end

Tags: php, ios, json, garbage

This is a really weird bug, when grabbing JSON from my server (which is produced via PHP), I get this error when calling:

```
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:kivaData
                                       options:kNilOptions
                                         error:&jsonError];
```

JSON Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x178467d00 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

My (NSData* kivaData) grabs everything perfectly, but it cant parse the JSON.

I have run my JSON code in http://jsonlint.com/ and it comes out Valid everytime.

Its really weird because it can parse the JSON when I connect to Wifi, but when I try doing it via cellular, it wont work. It does work over cellular on some peoples phones, but every time.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm seeing the same thing. My JSON response is 110k or so, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change my php file from echoing the json syntax to simply outputting with json_encode.

Answer (score 1):

using swift 4, first of all check the JSON Data using print :

```
print (String(data:data!, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

check for the white spaces or unwanted characters, then remove them :

```
var string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
string = string?.replacingOccurrences(of: "/r/n", with: "")
```

after that, assign the string back to data variable :

```
let data1 = string!.data(using: .utf8)
```

Answer (score 0):

encoding is very important. If your json is valid, the issue might be you have special characters in your json data, which is not correctly parsed by the json serializer. When you send the data, make sure you have the correct url-encoding when sending content so client will parse it correctly. Using  utf-8 always or base64.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem (works on wifi, but not on carrier network) by sending a content-length header just before the response:

```
header("Content-length: ".strlen($response));
echo $response;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

JsonData is usually stored in dictionary format. Since the json is not able to parse the continuous data[its not able to separate the responses] its throwing this error .

You can maintain a dictionary to store the responses obtained from server .
Each task will have a unique response . So create a dictionary with "keys" as "taskIdentifier" of tasks and "values" as "data".

Eg: 
Inside didReceiveData or any other equivalent methods [where you get response from server ] store response in dictionary with taskIdentifier as keys .

```
 NSString *taskID = [@(dataTask.taskIdentifier) stringValue];
[_task_data_dictionary setObject:data forKey:taskID];
```

Here _task_data_dictionary is the dictionary.In this way you can get rid of the above error .

After this you can get data using the same dictionary using this code

```
 NSData *data = [_task_data_dictionary objectForKey:taskNumber];
```

again using the taskIdentifier .

Hope this helps .